# estimate number of iterations to obtain an error

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

> The function 
>   $$
>  f : [-\pi, \pi] \to [-\pi,\pi] ,~~ f(x)= \frac{\sin(x)}{2}
> $$ 
>   is a contraction.
>   Hence the fixed point iteration $x_{k+1}= f(x_{k})$ starting from $x_{0}=\frac{\pi}{2} \in [-\pi , \pi]$ is converging to a fixed point $x^{*}$
>   How many iterations $k$ are at least necessary s.t. the error is guaranteed to satisfy $|x_{k}-x^{*}| \leq \frac{1}{1024}$

I hope I am not violating anything by reposting a question.
I've come pretty close to solving the question I think. But I need the last trick which I haven't figured out yet. So far I am at

$|\bar{x}-x_{n}| \leq \frac{q^{n}}{1-q}|f(x_{0})-x_{0}|$. 
I have determined q as $|f'(x)| max \ x \in [- \pi , \pi]=\frac{1}{2}=q$

so I have to determine n such that

$\frac{q^{n}}{1-q}|f(x_{0})-x_{0}| \leq \frac{1}{1024}$

=$\frac{q^{n}}{1-q}|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}| \leq \frac{1}{1024}$

=$\frac{q^{n}}{1-q}|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}| \leq \frac{1}{1024}$

and then I am not sure how to determine this n

Comment: $q^n\leq (1-q)/(1024|1/2-\pi/2|)$. Then, since $\log_{q}(x)$ is decreasing $n\geq\log_q((1-q)/(1024|1/2-\pi/2|))$.

Comment: can you always use this log trick when determining n?

Comment: actually I am a little bit confused about this method, is there any mor elementary way to determine it?

Comment: Yes. Brute force. Try $n=1,2,3,\dotsc$. You will be done around $n=12$. In the future, do *not* repost your question. Make a comment to a specific user to get her attention or edit your old question. Experienced users sort the questions by topic. There are not too many in numerical-methods, so your old question is not far down the (sorted) list.

Comment: It is not a trick. You have an inequality in which $n$ is the unknown. We need to solve it to determine when the inequality holds. In this particular case the inequality consists of a few functions applied, successively to $n$. Therefore, we can isolate $n$ by applying the inverse functions of each operation. There is a multiplication by $|1/2-\pi/2|$. The inverse is dividing by that. There is a division by $1-q$, so we divide by it. There is the exponentiation $q^n$. The inverse of the exponential is the logarithm.